# Scalextric start gate genie C20 pic

Tags: microcontroller, pic

I'm currently making my GCSE project and the deadline is quite soon, but i have a fair amount of issues still.  I am using a Genie C20 chip to programme a countdown that will indicate the start of a race on a scalextric track.  If a microswitch (in the scalextric track) is activated before the countdown is finished (the player has started early), an alarm will sound.  Can someone help me to work out why this circuit is not currently working?  Could it be something to do with the voltage regulator?[image]

[image]

Comment: Surely that would depend on how you've programmed the chip?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can someone help me to work out why this circuit is not currently
>   working?

PR should not be left open circuit (see [this](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0ahUKEwjL6_qv_OzRAhWEjZAKHSIEDsMQFggcMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.rapidonline.com%2Fpdf%2F13-6003.pdf&usg=AFQjCNGtcGs5GkTa-zSWs_xI6vP45t4cZQ&sig2=Cifvceo3dgRkp0ZA4iNfaA&cad=rja)) and the regulator may be OK (but not if it's a 7805 because it needs a decoupling capacitor on input and output). Also your chip needs decoupling capacitors from V+ to ground if more than an inch away from any regulator decoupling.

I suppose if only one LED is used at once they can all share one resistor but be aware that trying to activate multiple LEDs will progressively dim them.

You should also get into the practise of putting a resistor in series with the base on any BJT used like this - try a 470 ohm this time but different circuits need different values.

Have you correctly programmed the device?

Comment: i have added my programming but i dont believe that there is an issue with it.  What is the purpose of the 470 ohm resistor that you recommend?

Comment: Without the resistor, when your output pin goes high it will be clamped to about 0.8 volts by the base emitter junction and can lead to too much current being taken from the pin that may lead to a reset condition in the chip.